# How to i type this object from api response?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, next.js, types

```
{
    "_metadata": {
        "uid": "someuid"
    },
    "reference": [
        {
            "locale": "en-us",
             ... bunch of similar key:value
            "close_icon_size": "",
            "icons": {
                "default": {
                    "uid": "someuid",
                     ... bunch of similar key:value
                    "dimension": {
                        "height": 48,
                        "width": 48
                    },
                    "title": "bell-icon-new.svg",
                    "parent_uid": null,
                    "is_dir": false,
                    "url": "https://url.com"
                },
                ... bunch of similar repeated object
            },
            "link_text": "Text text tex",
            "styles": {
                "font_size": "24px",
                "width": "1400px",
                "font_color": {
                    "colorTheme": "custom",
                     ... bunch of similar key:value
                },
                "height": "75px",
                "link_text_size": "16px",
                "background_color": {
                    "colorTheme": "custom",
                     ... bunch of similar key:value
                },
                "font_family": "Arial",
                 ... bunch of similar key:value
            },
            "title": "Text",
            "_content_type_uid": "text text text"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am totally new to TypeScript. How do i type this kinds of objects? We have bunch of them which is slowing down my development?

I am planning to give type to each key:value but that will be exhausting job to do for large objects like this.

Any help would be apprerciated.

Thank you

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Where is this object coming from in the first place ?
If it's from a library, you can usually find the types definition either in it or in a different package.
If it's from a webservice, and it exposes a swagger (openapi), you can use opanapi-typescript to generate types

Comment: @jdel its coming from graphql api

Answer (score 3):

Just assign this object on a const and hover it in your IDE (at least works in VS Code).

You don't even have to specify this type, you can directly access the elements :

```
import React from 'react';

export function App(props) {
  const myVar = "yourJSON"
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{myVar.reference.locale}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Typescript needs type on dynamic objects

- If it comes from a webservice, just use tools like openapi-typescript to generate the types from a swagger
- If it comes from a library, check if there's a corresponding @type package.
- And in the worst case, just copy paste the type displayed when you hover your variable in your IDE

Comment: Thanks for the reply. When i hover it says `const data: any`.

Comment: const t = {
[...]
}

type MyType = typeof t